# How do I fix this 101 keeps showing at the end of result

Tags: java

How to remove the **101** that keeps showing on the code result? I was tasked to print the odd and even numbers from 0 - 100 but when I run my code, the number 101 keeps showing both at the end of Odd and Even results.

Here's my code so far;

```
public class act1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = 100;
        System.out.println("List of EVEN numbers");
        int evenNums = evenNumbers(start, end);
        System.out.println(evenNums);

        System.out.println("\nList of ODD numbers");
        int oddNums = oddNumbers(start, end);
        System.out.println(oddNums);
    }

    static int oddNumbers(int start, int end) {
        for (start = 0; start <= 100; start++) {
            if (start % 2 != 0) {
                System.out.print(start + " ");
            }
        }
        return start;
    }

    static int evenNumbers(int start, int end) {
        for (start = 0; start <= 100; start++) {
            if (start % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.print(start + " ");
            }
        }
        return start;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your for loop, `start` = 0 to 101,  total 101 records, try to modify to < 100, since it is beginning with zero to 100, total 101 records.

Comment: You are printing inside loop and then returning the last number that makes the loop condition false (101) for your case. Then from the main method printing the last number 101. Either return an array that contains all the odd / even number and print it from main or just return void and do all the printing from inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove those two : `System.out.println(oddNums);`, `System.out.println(evenNums);`.
It's printing 101 because when you return `return start;`, it will return the last index, which is the one on which the loop will break, which with this condition `start <= 100` will always be 101.

So here's the function with the edit already made :

```
public class act1 {  
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
    int start = 0;
    int end = 100;
    System.out.println("List of EVEN numbers");         
    evenNumbers(start, end);

    System.out.println("\nList of ODD numbers");    
    oddNumbers(start, end);
}
```

You don't need to get the return of the two functions, you can just call those like this.

Answer (score 0):

Reconsider how a for-loop works:

```
for (int n=0; n<=3; n++) {
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

- n==0, so n<=3 is true, enter the body and print out "0", n++ so n==1
- n==1, so n<=3 is true, enter the body and print out "1", n++ so n==2
- n==2, so n<=3 is true, enter the body and print out "2", n++ so n==3
- n==3, so n<=3 is true, enter the body and print out "3", n++ so n==4
- n==4, so n<=3 is false, terminate the loop

Now the value of n==4...